# QuickBlox Chat: can't perform video call

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm developing a video chat application with quickblox. And I have a trouble with performing video call. There are logs of two instances of application started in one time:

```
Sep 11 16:43:40 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: QBChat/didConnect
Sep 11 16:43:40 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:] -> user: 290427, supportsStartTLS: 1, isSecure: 0
Sep 11 16:43:40 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
Sep 11 16:43:40 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendIQ:] -> IQ: <iq type="get" id="561006823"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
Sep 11 16:43:41 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:] -> <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="561006823" type="result" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-3171"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
Sep 11 16:44:00 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
Sep 11 16:44:18 iPod-touch wifid[14] <Error>: WiFi:[400596258.779212]: Disable WoW requested by "UserEventAgent"
Sep 11 16:44:18 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: QBChat/didDisconnect, error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x1ed273e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
Sep 11 16:44:20 iPod-touch DimChat[3823] <Warning>: -[QBChat sendPresence] -> return. You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API
```

The second instance which calls the first one:

```
2013-09-11 16:43:46.408 DimChat[55216:b10f] QBChat/didConnect
2013-09-11 16:43:47.053 DimChat[55216:a207] -[QBChat xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:] -> user: 503867, supportsStartTLS: 1, isSecure: 0
2013-09-11 16:43:47.053 DimChat[55216:a207] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendIQ:] -> IQ: <iq type="get" id="561006823"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
2013-09-11 16:43:47.053 DimChat[55216:a207] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2013-09-11 16:43:47.215 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:] -> <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="561006823" type="result" to="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-3170"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
2013-09-11 16:43:56.295 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat init] -> 
2013-09-11 16:43:56.295 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat orientatioDidChange:] -> LandscapeLeft
2013-09-11 16:43:56.296 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat callUser:conferenceType:customParameters:] -> VideoChat configuration: {
    kQBVideoChatBadConnectionTimeout = 5;
    kQBVideoChatCallTimeout = 15;
    kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
    kQBVideoChatP2PTimeout = "1.5";
    kQBVideoChatTURNServerEndPoint = "turnserver.quickblox.com";
    kQBVideoChatVideoFramesPerSecond = 10;
    kQBVideoChatWriteQueueMaxAudioOperationsThreshold = 25;
    kQBVideoChatWriteQueueMaxVideoOperationsThreshold = 25;
}
2013-09-11 16:43:56.296 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="282475249" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:43:58.297 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="1622650073" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:00.298 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="984943658" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:02.300 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="1144108930" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:04.300 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="470211272" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:06.302 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="101027544" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:07.065 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2013-09-11 16:44:08.303 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="1457850878" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:10.303 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="1458777923" type="qbvideochat_call" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>1</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:11.304 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat finishCallWithStatus:customParameters:] -> kStopVideoChatCallStatus_OpponentDidNotAnswer
2013-09-11 16:44:11.305 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat deinitialization] -> 
2013-09-11 16:44:11.305 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat releaseVideoCapture] -> 
2013-09-11 16:44:11.306 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat releaseAudioCapture] -> 
2013-09-11 16:44:11.306 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBVideoChat releaseSocketConnection] -> 
2013-09-11 16:44:11.306 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="2007237709" type="qbvideochat_stopCall" to="290427-3936@chat.quickblox.com" from="503867-3936@chat.quickblox.com"><body>kStopVideoChatCallStatus_OpponentDidNotAnswer</body></message>
2013-09-11 16:44:25.264 DimChat[55216:b10f] QBChat/didDisconnect, error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x9ca1260 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
2013-09-11 16:44:27.074 DimChat[55216:b10f] -[QBChat sendPresence] -> return. You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API
```

Actually the problem is that the first instance didn't receive incoming call. 
I checked the video chat example from quickblox's github. It works with my users/passwords, so I have a mistake in my code, but I really don't know where I should search it.

As you can see both instances have the same problem: "Socket closed by remote peer". But this problem happens after call timeout, so it isn't a cause of main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. The problem was in QBVideoChat object. I thought that QBChat will send me the signal when another user calls me and then I'll create the QBVideoChat object and present it's view on screen.

The sad truth is that QBChat don't send any video relations signals before I create QBVideoChat. So I have to create it at program's start in order to receive chatDidReceiveCallRequestFromUser signal.

Comment: ok.then how did you solve ? i am getting same problem.checking for 2 days

Comment: I,m creating a QBVideoChat object at program start. 
_videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance];